# lenovo A7000 app not installed error and conflict key error

Tags: android, debugging

[image]I used lenovo A7000 as debugging phone and installed the apk but when trying to uninstall the app it is getting uninstalled but showing error as not installed in my app section of phone refer image for this .
and when i try to install signed apk , it is giving conflict key message.

Comment: I've seen this happen before. Try installing in another computer. Or using  `adb install -r'. Try other operations like restart your machine and devices.

Comment: Uninstall it from Settings rather than any shortcuts

Comment: i have uninstalled it from settings only see the image i have updated my question